# Starting Android Emulator in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net-maui

I'm having difficulties with starting up a project in .NET MAUI. I have the latest version of Visual Studio 2022, I have all Android SDK's installed, I've enabled Hyper-V to accelerate the emulating process, I've downloaded and installed the latest Android Device emulator (Google Pixel phone), and when I tried to run the program, debugger calls an error: "Error XA5301  Failed to generate Java type for class: AndroidX.Core.View.Accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat/ITouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor due to MAX_PATH: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Haris\Slovenija\Faks\Slovenija\Fakultet\Bachelor\Maribor\3. letnik\1. semestar\RMR\Vaje\Naloga_1\Naloga_1\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\android\src\mono\androidx\core\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor.java'.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String destination) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/Files.cs:line 170
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.CreateJavaSources(IEnumerable`1 javaTypes, TypeDefinitionCache cache) Naloga_1    C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1438"

I've been trying to fix this for last 10 days and it's really frustrating. Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like your path might be too long. Try moving your solution to a shorter path, like `C:\dev\myproject`

Comment: It seems the error message not about the emulator. Did you try to create a new project to test?

Comment: Moving to shorter path seemed to do the trick, thanks for the input